# merging sorted arrays versus merging sorted linked lists

Tags: arrays, sorting, linked-list

Which is faster, merging two sorted arrays of lengths n and m or merging two sorted linked lists of lengths n and m.

I need a data structure to store a collection of items on which I will only ever need to perform two operations:

pop() to return and remove the first item of this list.

and merge() to merge two sorted lists.

As these are the only operations I need to preform to seems to me that the most efficient solution is a linked list however arrays may be better or possibly there exists a third option superior to both.

I have an upper bound on the lengths of the lists that is specified before compile time but I would like to be able to vary this upper bound. For example, before I run the program I may know that the list lengths will be at most 10000 but I may then want to run the program again with lists of lengths less than 1000000.

Also, if arrays are the better option then how does one merge arrays efficiently? it is clear to me how this is done with linked lists but with arrays it would seem that you would need to constantly be shifting the content down which would be very inefficient.

Thanks for the help

Comment: LinkedLists require more overhead than arrays typically... LinkedLists are used when the size of the data is unknown.

Comment: To merge two arrays you would want to allocate enough memory to contain the merged array and then copy the values in one by one. This will probably be faster than merging two linked lists as the elements of an array are stored contiguously in memory, which means the CPU caches can be used efficiently. But you should test it yourself, as your specific use case may give unexpected results.

Comment: Assuming there's no push(), and that pop() could just increment an index or a pointer to an array, effectively reducing the array size by 1, then an array would be faster. If the merge() is allowed to create a new array of the same size as the sum of the sizes of the two original arrays (optionally freeing or deleting the two original arrays), then merge() would be faster with arrays.